# websockets not working work on python3.6.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

The piece of code below, works fine for python3.7

```
import websockets
import asyncio

async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
    res = await ws.recv()
```

but with python 3.6, i'm getting this error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can some one explain the problem. Thanks.

Comment: The `async` keyword was new in Python 3.7. So in Python 3.6 that is invalid syntax.

Comment: thx, how can i make web socket connection in 3.6? could you give an example? most of i found is only works for 3.7...